# How can I change the map size and the origin?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, resolution, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

```
   I have made a map successfully,but it was not so good. How can I change the map size through the gmapping parameters? 
   The map is useless because there are so many unknown regions , so the map looks so little in the middle of the picture. Although I modified the parameter (max_Range, max_Urange ,x_min and  so on（gmapping）)，but I still can not get a good result. 
   Now my map ：pan.baidu.com/s/1jGwnoto .
   the map I really want is just like : pan.baidu.com/s/1eQzdnea (sorry that's a link, please copy it).
```

By the way, How can I make the origin(.yaml file) [0 0 0]?

Best Regards!

Gerald

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112336/how-can-i-change-the-map-size-and-the-origin?/) by [Gerald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3133/gerald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to change the xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax parameters, maxRange and maxUrange (without underscore) are for laser!! You can find the complete list of parameters [here](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping#Parameters).

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0